# Bluetooth media buttons don't work when phone is locked

Tags: lock-screens, bluetooth, media-button

I have bluetooth headphones (Anker) which include a play/pause button. This button only works when the phone (Nokia 3.1) is unlocked.

How can I enable bluetooth media buttons to work when the screen is locked?

Comment: Is this behaviour noticed for a particular app you are using to play music? Maybe that app is getting dozed - try removing that app from battery optimization

Comment: How? I can't see per-app stuff in the battery section of the settings

Comment: I am on Android 10. You need to locate battery optimization in settings -  similar to this https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-remove-android-apps-from-the-battery-optimization-list/

Comment: This is better - https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Also if you are using any battery saving apps, disable or uninstall them